# Changing the active range to a newly generated sheet causing error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Receiving the error,

> ReferenceError: "setActiveSelection" is not defined.

Using Google Apps Script on Google Sheets. With this function, I'm wanting to create a new sheet tab on the same workbook using a template from another workbook. Once the new sheet is created, I'd like to change the actively selected cell to cell 'B1'. The template is copying fine, but the error is coming from the line changing the active selection. I've also tried `setActiveRange` and even just `setActiveSheet` but they return the same error.

```
function newReception() {  
  var templateSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID Redacted");
  var template = templateSpreadsheet.getSheets()[1]; 

  var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = template.copyTo(currentSpreadsheet).setName("Untitled 
   Reception");

  setActiveSelection(currentSpreadsheet.getSheetbyName("Untitled 
   Reception").getRange('B1'));

}
```

Please advise on a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this issue because you're running `.setActiveSelection()` on its own. This method is bound to sheets, so you must run it for such. See [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setActiveSelection(String)) documentation for more details on this method.

Try defining your sheet as a variable and then running it for your new sheet variable.

```
var sheet = currentSpreadsheet.getSheetbyName("Untitled Reception");
sheet.setActiveSelection('B1');
```

Comment: Thanks, figured it out from this. Your code was giving me the error "TypeError: Cannot find function getSheetbyName in object Spreadsheet." but I was able to fix it by not using the currentSpreadsheet variable and writing it instead as  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Untitled Reception");

Not sure what was causing the second error, but it's addressed now. Thanks for the help!